# How to add ipython notebook to github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

So, I have a blog which is hosted on github pages.

I havent blogged much but whatever little I have done has been adding `*.md` files in `_posts` directory which I have.

What would be the simplest way of adding an ipython notebook to my blog.. 
For reference, I have followed this tutorial here while setting up my blog.
https://github.com/hankquinlan/hankquinlan.github.io

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is `$ ipython nbconvert your_notebook.ipynb --to markdown`.
For a longer answer, check out this [link](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbconvert.html) from iPython website